# How do you find out if PDF Textbox field is multi-line using ABCpdf?

Tags: c#, pdf, abcpdf

I can loop through all the fields in a PDF using ABCpdf using the GetFieldNames() collection and get their properties but the one I can't seem to get is whether or not the field is multi-line text field or not.  Is there any example out there of how to find this property?  My code is below if it's helpful but it's probably unnecessary.

```
    ....

    foreach (string fieldName in doc.Form.GetFieldNames())
    {
        WebSupergoo.ABCpdf9.Objects.Field f = doc.Form[fieldName];
        dt = GetFieldInstances(dt,f);
    }

    ....

    private static DocumentTemplate GetFieldInstances(DocumentTemplate dt, WebSupergoo.ABCpdf9.Objects.Field f)
    {
        Field field;
        Instance inst = new Instance(); 
        int instanceCount = 0;
        bool fieldAlreadyExists = dt.Fields.Any(currentField => currentField.Name == f.Name);
        if (!fieldAlreadyExists)
        {
            field = new Field();
            field.Name = f.Name;
            field.Value = f.Value;
            field.Format = f.Format == null ? null : f.Format;
            field.PartialName = f.PartialName;
            field.TypeID = (int)f.FieldType;

            //field.IsMultiline = 
            //field.IsRequired = 
        }
        else
        {
            field = (from currentField in dt.Fields where currentField.Name == f.Name select currentField).SingleOrDefault();
            instanceCount = field.Instances.Count();
        }

        if ((Field.FieldTypes)f.FieldType == Field.FieldTypes.Radio || (Field.FieldTypes)f.FieldType == Field.FieldTypes.Checkbox)
        {
            inst.ExportValue = f.Options[instanceCount];
        }
        if (f.Kids.Count() > 0)
        {
            f = f.Kids[instanceCount];
        }
        inst.Bottom = (int)f.Rect.Bottom;
        inst.Height = (int)f.Rect.Height;
        inst.Left = (int)f.Rect.Left;
        inst.Width = (int)f.Rect.Width;
        inst.PageNumber = f.Page.PageNumber;




        field.Instances.Add(inst);

        if (!fieldAlreadyExists)
        {
            dt.Fields.Add(field);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
public bool GetIsMultiLine(WebSupergoo.ABCpdf9.Objects.Field field)
{
    var flags = Atom.GetInt(Atom.GetItem(field.Atom, "Ff"));
    var isMultiLine = GetIsBitFlagSet(flags, 13);
    return isMultiLine;
}

public bool GetIsRequired(WebSupergoo.ABCpdf9.Objects.Field field)
{
    var flags = Atom.GetInt(Atom.GetItem(field.Atom, "Ff"));
    var isRequired = GetIsBitFlagSet(flags, 2);
    return isRequired;
}

public bool GetIsReadOnly(WebSupergoo.ABCpdf9.Objects.Field field)
{
    var flags = Atom.GetInt(Atom.GetItem(field.Atom, "Ff"));
    var isReadOnly = GetIsBitFlagSet(flags, 1);
    return isReadOnly;
}

private static bool GetIsBitFlagSet(int b, int pos)
{
    return (b & (1 << (pos - 1))) != 0;
}
```

In case your not familiar with unsigned integer / binary conversions, [I found this site really helpful to understand.](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_unsigned_int.html?hexadecimal=00001000)

For example, let's say that the integer returned for a field's flags equals 4096.  If you enter that into the [online coversion tool](http://www.binaryconvert.com/convert_unsigned_int.html) in that website, it will show you that the 13th bit position is turned on (1 instead of a 0 in the 13th position starting from the right).

In the ABCPdf guide, it says that Multi-Line is bit position 13 so you know that field is a Multi-Line field.

Likewise for the 2nd position for Required and the 1st position for Read-only.